# Erro ao tentar rowCount em classe com PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou a tentar fazer um rowCount utilizando uma classe que eu mesmo desenvolvi para a conexão e algumas funções envolvendo o bd.

Possuo a seguinte classe PHP:

```
class Banco {
    private $debug;
    private static $pdo;

    function __construct($debug = true, $banco = "BANCO", $usuario = "USUARIO", $senha = "SENHA") {
        $this->debug = $debug;

        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=".$banco, $usuario, $senha);

            if($debug) {
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }

            $this->pdo->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $this->pdo->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
            $this->pdo->query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
            $this->pdo->query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            if($this->debug) {
                echo "Ocorreu um erro de conexão: " .$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    public function consultar($tabela, $colunas, $condicao, $agrupamento, $ordenacao, $limite) {
        try {
            if(is_array($colunas)) {
                $colunas = implode(", ", $colunas);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT " .$colunas. " FROM " .$tabela;

            if($condicao != false) {
                $sql .= " WHERE " .$condicao;
            }

            if($agrupamento != false) {
                $sql .= " GROUP BY " .$agrupamento;
            }

            if($ordenacao != false) {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " .$ordenacao;
            }

            if($limite != false) {
                $sql .= " LIMIT " .$limite;
            }

            return $this->pdo->query($sql);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function contaLinha($sql) {
        try {
            $var = $this->pdo->query($sql);

            return $this->pdo->rowCount($var);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

e um outro arquivo, também em PHP, que precisa desse rowCount:

```
$bd = new Banco();

$colunas = array("nome", "email", "teste", "codigo", "estatus");

$sql = $bd -> consultar("TABELA", "$colunas", "codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0", false, false, 1);

if($bd -> contaLinha($sql)) {
    echo "Contou!";
} else {
    echo "Retornou 0!";
}
```

Porém, ao tentar executar tais códigos, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> *Ocorreu um erro: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'*
>
> *Ocorreu um erro: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty*

E, como sou iniciante em PHPOO, surgiram algumas dúvidas:

1. Já tentei utilizar a função `consultar()` sem array para testar mas não
   ocorreram muitas mudanças. Acredito que o erro não está na classe. O
   que posso estar fazendo de errado?
2. Devo utilizar `private` ou `public` na `function __construct()` ou
   deixar como está?

**Obrigado!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, Pelo que li na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php) a função rowCount não recebe parametro.

> *"Retorna o número de linhas afetadas pelo último DELETE, INSERT ou UPDATE executada pelo objeto PDOStatement correspondente.*
>
> *Se a última instrução SQL executado pelo PDOStatement associada foi uma instrução SELECT, alguns bancos de dados podem retornar o número
>   de linhas retornadas por essa afirmação. No entanto, esse
>   comportamento não é garantida para todos os bancos de dados e não deve
>   ser invocado para aplicações portáteis."*

Segundo, repare no retorno de `consultar` :

`return $this->pdo->query($sql);`

e agora olhe a primeira função que vc chama no conta linha

`$var = $this->pdo->query($sql);`

agora confira a ordem  das chamadas que você faz;

```
$sql = $bd -> consultar("TABELA", "$colunas", "codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0", false, false, 1);

//o contaLinha está esperando uma String pois dentro dele vc chama a função $this->pdo->query($sql)
if($bd -> contaLinha($sql))
```

Resumindo o que acontece é isso
`$this->pdo->query($this->pdo->query($sql))`;

Uma sugestão para você é que existe uma função nativa do php que conta quantos elementos tem um array, a função se chama [count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php)

**Solução**

```
class Banco{

    //removi o static  
    private $pdo;

    public function consultar($tabela, $colunas, $condicao, $agrupamento, $ordenacao, $limite) {
        try {
            if(is_array($colunas)) {
                $colunas = implode(", ", $colunas);
            }else{//caso nao for array, vc pode tratar de outra forma
                $colunas =" * ";
            }

            $sql = "SELECT " .$colunas. " FROM " .$tabela;

            if($condicao != false) {
                $sql .= " WHERE " .$condicao;
            }

            if($agrupamento != false) {
                $sql .= " GROUP BY " .$agrupamento;
            }

            if($ordenacao != false) {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " .$ordenacao;
            }

            if($limite != false) {
                $sql .= " LIMIT " .$limite;
            }

            //modifiquei o retorno 
            $result = $this->pdo->query($sql);
            return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

O outro arquivo que chama as funções do banco.

```
$bd = new Banco();

$colunas = array("nome", "email", "teste", "codigo", "estatus");

//aqui eu tirei as aspas da variavel $coluna pois estava dando erro
$result = $bd->consultar("TABELA", $colunas, "codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0", false, false, 1);

//verifico se a quantidade é maior que zero
if(count($result)>0){
    echo "Contou!";
} else {
    echo "Retornou 0!";
}

//se quiser navegar nos registros faça assim
if(count($result)>0){
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $value['nome'];
        echo $value['email'];
        //code...
    }
}
```

A sua função conta_linha pode ser assim, independente do resultado de outra função. Ela só retorna a quantidade de registro que existe de acordo com a condição passada.

```
public function conta_linha($tabela, $condicao) {
    try {

        $sql = "SELECT count(id) as cont FROM " .$tabela;

        if($condicao != false) {
            $sql .= " WHERE " .$condicao;
        }

        //modifiquei o retorno 
        $result = $this->pdo->query($sql);
        return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas, antes de usar a classe estava fazendo a função de conexão e o rowCount diretamente e funcionava perfeitamente.

Comment: Adicionei mais alguns detalhes

Comment: Eu percebi isso, e então, tentei também $bd -> contaLinha ("SELECT pname, email, teste, codigo , estatus from TABELA WHERE codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0") porém não funcionou também...

Comment: Gerou qual erro assim? o nome da coluna é pname ou nome? por que la na descrição voce usa nome

Comment: Eu fiz assim:

$sql = "SELECT pname, email, teste, codigo, estatus from TABELA WHERE codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0";

e então:

$bd -> contaLinha($sql);

E gerou:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount()...

Comment: Testei aqui o código e aquele erro `Ocorreu um erro: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'Retornou 0!` é por causa que esta passando a variavel $colunas entre aspas para a função consultar.

Comment: e se $colunas for NULL ou diferente de array voce precisa tratar.

Comment: Então no caso eu terei que utilizar a função consultar junto com a contaLinha?

Comment: Me diga uma coisa no consultar voce quer que devolve todos os dados do banco de dados certo?

Comment: Me desculpe ali em cima, eu havia colocado um código antigo aqui, mas o correto é nome e não pname... Em relação ao consultar eu quero que ele faça a consulta e faça o rowCount pra eu poder saber se o retorno de alguém com codigo = '$getT' AND estatus = 0" é maior que 0 ou igual a 0 e assim fazer outras verificações após isso.

Comment: Adicionei a solução, espero que seja o que precisa, as partes que eu mudei eu deixei comentado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio, @Abraão. Funcionou!